# configure command doesn't generate Makefile?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile

Here is my code:

```
    ubuntu@ubuntu:~/tpm2-tss$ ./configure --enable-unit
    checking for gcc... gcc
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
    checking for suffix of executables... 
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
    checking for suffix of object files... o
    checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
    checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
    checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
    checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
    ./configure: line 3119: syntax error near unexpected token              `am__api_version='1.15''
    ./configure: line 3119: `am__api_version='1.15''
```

so after i execute make check i get (code below) which means it wasnt created thanks for help

```
    ubuntu@ubuntu:~/tpm2-tss$ make check
    make: *** No rule to make target 'check'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04, 17.10, 18.04 : Source package `tpm2-tss` → The following binary packages are built from this source package: 16.04 → `libtss2-0, libtss2-dev, libtss2-utils`. ... 17.10, 18.04 → `libsapi-dev, libsapi-utils, libsapi0`. ( All built with `--enable-unit`.) ... So you can actually install the "tpm2-tss" packages with apt.

Answer (score 0):

This is a failure of `autotools` configuration. Autotools generates the `./configure` script with `autoscan` and there is a problem with that step. File a bug report upstream.

Guessing they have one to many single-quotes

```
am__api_version='1.15''
```

versus,

```
am__api_version='1.15'
```